# Why is this dynamic select box not working with jQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I found out that this [chained select box](http://buffernow.com/cascading-dropdown-ajax/) that uses PHP / MySQL / AJAX / jQuery isn't functioning with jQuery1.9.1. The first select box works fine, but when I select the second one, which uses type_list.php to retrieve data from sql, it fails to pull any data even though the php file is triggered. Anyone know why it isn't working with jQuery 1.9.1?

jQuery 1.9.1: [Example](http://painfulmouth.com/indexjq.php) - not working.

jQuery 1.7.2: [Example](http://www.bkrenew.net16.net/bksearch/indexjq.php) - works fine.

type_list.php:

```
<?php
// list of printer types for specific manufacturer
include("dbconfig.inc.php");

header("Content-type: text/xml");

$manid = $_POST['man'];

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
echo "<printertypes>\n";
$select = "SELECT type_id, type_text FROM printer_types WHERE man_id = '".$manid."'";
try {
    foreach($dbh->query($select) as $row) {
        echo "<Printertype>\n\t<id>".$row['type_id']."</id>\n\t<name>".$row['type_text']."</name>\n</Printertype>\n";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
echo "</printertypes>";
?>
```

JS Code:

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function($){

$('#loading')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;



// Ajax Called When Page is Load/Ready (Load Manufacturer)
jQuery.ajax({
                      url: 'man_list.php',
                      global: false,
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "xml",
                      async: false, 
                      success: populateComp
                }); 



//Ajax Called When You Change  Manufaturer
$("#manufacturer").change(function () 
    {
     resetValues(); 

        var data = { man :$(this).attr('value') };
    jQuery.ajax({
                      url: 'type_list.php',
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "xml",
                      data:data,
                      async: false, 
                      success: populateType
                }); 
    });

//Ajax Called When You Change Type of Printer
$("#printertype").change(function () 
    {

        var data = { 
        man :$('#manufacturer').val(),
        typ : $(this).attr('value')
        };
    jQuery.ajax({
                      url: 'model_list.php',
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "xml",
                      data:data,
                      async: false, 
                      success: populateModel
                }); 
    });

//Do What You Want With Result .......... :)
    $("#printermodel").change(function () 
    {

//'you select Model='+$('#manufacturer').val()+'type='+$('#printertype').val()+'And Model='+$('#printermodel').val()
alert('you select Model = '+$('#manufacturer option:selected').text()+' ,type= '+$('#printertype option:selected').text()+' And Model = '+$('#printermodel option:selected').text()
);
    });



                    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know why it isn't working with jQuery 1.9.1?

Well first of all, *if* you had done a little debugging yourself (why haven’t you?), you would have seen that no value for `man` parameter is passed in the AJAX POST request to the server.

Using the JavaScript debugger in FireBug, it becomes obvious quickly, that this line is at fault:

```
var data = { man :$(this).attr('value') };
```

And the documentation for [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) tells you, that this should only be used to query values that where explicitly set – which is not the case for the `select` element.

So use `.val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```